# My css and html are structured very weirdly, how can I make it so that my chat window resizes with the browser?

Tags: html, css, resize, window, chat

I'm just about done my chat server for an assignment and I've gotten most of the key features done, one of them thanks to you guys. I just need one more small thing and I'm not too sure how to do it.

I need to make it so that my chat can resize with the browser. So far it resizes horizontally but it won't resize vertically. I tried setting all my heights to a percentage but it didn't resize with the window.

I'd like to make it fill the whole window when maximized and as I shrink the window, everything shrinks with me. I want it to resize with the window while keep all the mostly relatively together. How can I do this? Thanks.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- title of app -->
        <div id = "title">
            <h2>SENG 513 Chat</h2>
        </div>

        <!--username-->
        <div id="usernameIndicator">
        </div>

        <div id ="currentOnline">   
                <p><b>Currently Online</b></p>
        </div>
        <!--chat messages and online users-->
        <div id ="main">

            <div id="messageArea">
                <ul id="messages"></ul>
            </div>

            <div id ="clear">
            </div>

            <div id ="usernames">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--chat and message bar-->
        <form action ="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, img {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;.
}

body{
    font-family:helvetica;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:#3a6db7;
    padding: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#title {
    text-align:center;
    color:#e8bf2e;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
}

#usernameIndicator h2
{
    color:#e8842e;
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#currentOnline{
}

#main
{
    height:500px;

}

#messageArea{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#messages{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;

    max-height:100%;



}

#messages li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #eee;
}

#usernames{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border: 1px solid;
    width:9%;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#messagebarArea{
    width:100%;
}
#form{
    width:100%;


}

form input { 
     width:90%;
     margin-top:20px;
     margin-bottom:20px;
     border-radius:5px;

}

form button {
    width: 9%; 
    background: rgb(130, 244, 255); 
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set #main as a percentage it should scale with the page height. Right now it seems to be constraining its height at 500px. You can additionally set 500px as the min-height so it remains visible at small window sizes.

Comment: Hey Adam again lol. I tried that #main height as just a percentage but when i drag the window up past the chat message area and button, it doens't resize with me, it just hides.

Comment: It's all good, it was a minor feature. I submitted my assignment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, img {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;.
}

body{
    font-family:helvetica;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:#3a6db7;
    padding: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
    margin:auto;
    height:100vh;
}
#title {
    text-align:center;
    color:#e8bf2e;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
}

#usernameIndicator h2
{
    color:#e8842e;
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#currentOnline{
}

#main
{
    height:calc(100vh - 150px);

}

#messageArea{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#messages{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;

    max-height:100%;



}

#messages li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #eee;
}

#usernames{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border: 1px solid;
    width:9%;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#messagebarArea{
    width:100%;
}
#form{
    width:100%;


}

form input { 
     width:90%;
     margin-top:20px;
     margin-bottom:20px;
     border-radius:5px;

}

form button {
    width: 9%; 
    background: rgb(130, 244, 255); 
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- title of app -->
        <div id = "title">
            <h2>SENG 513 Chat</h2>
        </div>

        <!--username-->
        <div id="usernameIndicator">
        </div>

        <div id ="currentOnline">   
                <p><b>Currently Online</b></p>
        </div>
        <!--chat messages and online users-->
        <div id ="main">

            <div id="messageArea">
                <ul id="messages"></ul>
            </div>

            <div id ="clear">
            </div>

            <div id ="usernames">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--chat and message bar-->
        <form action ="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also on jsfiddle.net: https://jsfiddle.net/3gwfw5bc/2/

There are two differences between jsfiddle version and above version; I set `min-height: 150px` for `#main` and `min-height: 300px` for `#wrapper` in fiddle but didn't do here. Because it doesn't fit the small screen in code demo in here and you got disappointed in first sight! But should consider it in action in case of small devices.

Comment: It made it a little better. As good as it could be for my layout I think. Thanks!